# Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException Mule ESB

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, mule, esb

I am using external jar in my mule flow. Jar file make database connection in postgres database. Standalone jar file working fine. But when I use this jar file in my mule it give error

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://xxx/xxx
```

I have add postgres jar file in both application as external jar(mule application & standalone jar)

Answer (score 1):

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql` exception come when Java don't find driver from jar file provided.

you have make sure that jar is correct and it present in your project class path.

Comment: Is it present in your class-path, is jar accesible to your framework, is `lib` folder present in your project then put it in that folder and configure in class path.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://xxx/xxx` clearly says that the jar files is not detected in the classpath .. Now if you are using Mule Standalone you could add the jar in the location `${standaone_installation_folder}/lib/user`

and if you are using Mule/anypoint studio you can add by right clicking the project and select java build path and then select add external jar where you select `postgresql-jdbc3.jar`
or alternately you can also create a `lib` folder in your project and put the jar file there and then right click on the jar file and add it into classpath

Answer (score 0):

When using Anypoint studio, I would rather play by it's rules to make sure you overcome any classloader hierarchy problems. Postgresql is not supported with a simplified configuration, but in the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector#DatabaseConnector-AddingtheDatabaseDriver) you'll find that the example actually explains how to use postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

To install the database driver for a generic installation in Studio Visual Editor, follow the steps below:

1. If you haven't already done so, download the driver for your particular database. For example, the driver for a MySQL database is available for download online.
2. Add the driver's .jar file to the root folder in your project. In Studio, you can drag and drop the file from your local drive into the project folder.
3. Add the .jar file to the build path of your project. Right click the project name, then select Build Path > Configure Build Path…
4. In the wizard that appears, click the Libraries tab, then click Add Jars…
5. Navigate to the root folder in your project, then select the .jar file for your database driver.
6. Click OK to save, then OK to exit the wizard. Notice that your project now has a new folder named Referenced Libraries in which your database driver .jar resides.